# jquery help understanding a specific variable is following code

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm pulling this code out of a tutorial that works... I don't understand where `index` comes from ??

```
$('.thumbnail_container a.thumbnail').each(function(index) {

    var remainder = (index%max_C)/100;
    var maxIndex = 0;
    /* debug */ $('.debug-remainder').append(remainder+'-');    

    if(remainder == 0) {
        if(index !=0) {
            thumbnail_R += thumbnailHeight;
        }
        thumbnail_C = 0;
    } else {
        thumbnail_C += thumbnailWidth;
    }

});
```

Comment: Have you looked up the jQuery `.each()` method's documentation??

Answer (score 1):

`index` is the first parameter passed into `.each()` by default: [here's the documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: ooops... Yes ... I see that now.. My first time working with jQuery, so now have a place to study more..  Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Per the jQuery .each() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

You can pass two parameters to this function. Index, which is the index of the current item in the list of matching elements, and valueOfElement, which is the value of the current element in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to your `.each()` callback function is the `index` of the current iteration of the loop (*starting from 0*)

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/F7Ts5/

http://api.jquery.com/each/